# How to get csv file printed with the same format as when it's opened with a notepad app?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following structure

```
  animal  |   description
 ---------+----------------
   dog    |      mammal
   cat    |  feline mammal
   shark  |     big fish
```

I would like to print the dataframe like this:

```
0;animal;description
1;dog;mammal
2;cat;feline mammal
3;shark;big fish
```

in order to copy the dataframe into the clipboard.
I want to know if there is a straightfoward solution with pandas instead of looping around each row and casting.
if I try to print it I will just get this result:

```
print(df.values)
array([['0,animal,description;;'],
       ['1,dog,mammal;;'],
       ['2,cat,feline mammal;;'],
       ['3,shark,big fish;;']],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the _file_ or print the data that is stored in Pandas?

Comment: I'm trying to bring a csv file through a vpn remote connection that doesn't allow to move files from one device to another, the only way to do that is via the clipboard. In order to that, it's easier for me to just paste the clipboard's data into a file and save it with a `.csv` extension in the local device

Comment: So are you trying to print the _file_ or the data that was parsed by Pandas? The raw file and the Pandas data are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `.csv` file you can read it and print line by line like this:

```
with open('data.csv') as file:
   lines = file.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       print(line, end='')
   data.close()
```

You would get the following output:

```
0;animal;description
1;dog;mammal
2;cat;feline mammal
3;shark;big fish
```

Comment: This worked! , thanks. I didn't think about doing it without loading into pandas

Comment: You didn't close your quotes